# LESS - saturate color code using javascript / jquery

Tags: jquery, css, less

As per [LESSCSS documentation](http://lesscss.org/), i can apply saturation like below in LESS file.

```
background-color: saturate(#A0F809, 25%);
```

But i am going to populate a list in javascript and each list item has it's own background color. And i need to apply hover color by saturating 25% from it's background color. How can i do this in javascript / jquery?

I tried LESS parser. But it expects me to pass css class, it is not accepting css style.

**This works:**

```
parser = new(less.Parser);
parser.parse('.class{background-color: saturate(#CD6667, 25%)}', function(err, tree) {console.log(tree.toCSS())})
```

**But not this:**

```
parser = new(less.Parser);
parser.parse('background-color: saturate(#CD6667, 25%)', function(err, tree) {console.log(tree.toCSS())})
```

Comment: Can you set up an example in a jsfiddle? also, what's the error message?

Comment: you can directly try above code in console from http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. You can call most of [these functions](http://lesscss.org/#reference) like below.

```
color = "#235689";
color = color.replace("#", "");

//get less color object
color = new less.tree.Color(color); 

//saturate it 50%
color = less.tree.functions.saturate(color, {value: 50}).toCSS();
```

now `color` returns 50% saturated color.